# What less obvious tests could this be failing on?

Tags: algorithm, tree

`Given a binary tree t and an integer s, determine whether there is a root to leaf path in t such that the sum of vertex values equals s.`

On Codesignal, I tried solving the practice interview problem above with the code below:

It passed the "visible tests" but said that the code fails the "hidden tests". There's no way to guess what the hidden tests are but any suggestions?

```
//
// Binary trees are already defined with this interface:
// class Tree<T> {
//   Tree(T x) {
//     value = x;
//   }
//   T value;
//   Tree<T> left;
//   Tree<T> right;
// }
boolean hasPathWithGivenSum(Tree<Integer> t, int s) {
    return s == sum(t, s);
}

int sum(Tree<Integer> t, int s) {
    int currSum = 0;
    if(t == null)
        return 0;
    else {
        int currVal = 0;
        try {
            currVal = (int)(t.value);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            // ignore
        }
        currSum += currVal;
        currSum += sum(t.left, s) + sum(t.right, s);
    }
    return currSum;
}
```

Comment: The task here is to check whether any of the paths from the root to a leaf sums to the given number. That means that from each branch node, you get two different sums. Your code calculates only one sum of all nodes in the tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From these these two lines in your code:

```
currSum += currVal;
currSum += sum(t.left, s) + sum(t.right, s);
```

You see that you are accumulating current node's value to the `currSum` and then accumulate what is there on the left tree and what is there on the right tree. 
In effect, you are computing the total of all node values.

Instead you need to check sum along a path from root to the leaf node. The way you do it is:

a) As you go along from root to leaf accumulate the current sum. - but you need to be careful that you don't keep accumulating after you return from a leaf! The way to do it is just pass the `current sum + current node's value` to next recursive call. So when that call is done, the `current sum` retains its original value.

b) As soon as you get to a leaf , check if your current sum is equal to target sum, if yes return true;

This can be achieved by doing a depth first approach as below:

```
private boolean hasSumToLeaf( Tree<Integer> root, int currSum, int target ) {
    if ( root == null ) return false;
    if ( root.left == null && root.right == null && currSum + root.value == target ) return true;
    return hasSumToLeaf( root.left, currSum + root.value, target ) 
    ||
    hasSumToLeaf( root.right, currSum + root.value, target );
}
```

You could call this method as: `return hasSumToLeaf( root, 0, s );` where `0` represents currently accumulated sum and `s` is the target sum.

Answer (score 2):

The question expects you to check if there exists a path from root to leaf with sum of all values in that path same as `s`.

What you are doing is calculating entire subtree sum and comparing it with the target value.

[image]

Consider the above tree. Let's say we are looking for sum `8` which has a path `1-> 2 -> 5` . With your code, you are actually returning value `11` to root node `1` which is the value of the entire left subtree.

**Solution:** You instead pass a sum value as an extra parameter in the method call from top to bottom where you add the current node Val to sum before you call it's subtree and have checks when you hit a leaf node.